# Reporting services report to DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I can get to the point of comma delimited string via:

```
byte[] bytes = rvMain.ServerReport.Render("csv", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

string CsvBody = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
```

But, I need the data in a datatable.

Please can somebody help me to do this?

I can't do a split on the CSV, because it has optional quotes on it and I don't know how to switch them off.

I can create a datatable from the query, but the report has two date parameters on it, so if I could access the values of those I'd be okay too.

I've hit a brick wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written five methods below.

They have been designed to take into account optional quote marks (e.g. " symbols) and to be as versatile as possible without using other libraries:

```
    public static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string filePath, bool isHeadings)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser TextFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
            {
                if (isHeadings)
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParser(TextFieldParser);

                }
                else
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParserNoHeadings(TextFieldParser);

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }

    public static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsvString(string csvBody, bool isHeadings)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            MemoryStream MemoryStream = new MemoryStream();


            StreamWriter StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(MemoryStream);

            StreamWriter.Write(csvBody);

            StreamWriter.Flush();


            MemoryStream.Position = 0;


            using (TextFieldParser TextFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(MemoryStream))
            {
                if (isHeadings)
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParser(TextFieldParser);

                }
                else
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParserNoHeadings(TextFieldParser);

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }

    public static DataTable GetDataTableFromRemoteCsv(string url, bool isHeadings)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            StreamReader StreamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

            using (TextFieldParser TextFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(StreamReader))
            {
                if (isHeadings)
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParser(TextFieldParser);

                }
                else
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParserNoHeadings(TextFieldParser);

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }


    private static DataTable GetDataTableFromTextFieldParser(TextFieldParser textFieldParser)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            textFieldParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });

            textFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;


            string[] ColumnFields = textFieldParser.ReadFields();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (string ColumnField in ColumnFields)
            {
                DataColumn DataColumn = new DataColumn(ColumnField);

                DataColumn.AllowDBNull = true;

                dt.Columns.Add(DataColumn);

            }


            while (!textFieldParser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] Fields = textFieldParser.ReadFields();


                for (int i = 0; i < Fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Fields[i] == "")
                    {
                        Fields[i] = null;

                    }

                }

                dt.Rows.Add(Fields);

            }

            MethodResult = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }

    private static DataTable GetDataTableFromTextFieldParserNoHeadings(TextFieldParser textFieldParser)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            textFieldParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });

            textFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            bool FirstPass = true;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            while (!textFieldParser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] Fields = textFieldParser.ReadFields();

                if(FirstPass)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Fields.Length; i++)
                    {
                        DataColumn DataColumn = new DataColumn("Column " + i);

                        DataColumn.AllowDBNull = true;

                        dt.Columns.Add(DataColumn);

                    }

                    FirstPass = false;

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < Fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Fields[i] == "")
                    {
                        Fields[i] = null;

                    }

                }

                dt.Rows.Add(Fields);

            }

            MethodResult = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }
```

If, like me, you're saving from reporting services then you should use it like this:

```
    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamids;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string filenameExtension;

    byte[] bytes = rvMain.ServerReport.Render("csv", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

    string CsvBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

    DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromCsvString(CsvBody,true);
```

Otherwise, all you need do is:

```
    bool IsHeadings = true; //Does the data include a heading row?

    DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromCsvString(CsvBody, IsHeadings);
```

Or to use directly from a csv file

```
    bool IsHeadings = true; //Does the data include a heading row?

    DataTable dt = GetDataTabletFromCsvFile(FilePath, IsHeadings)
```

Or to use a csv file that is stored remotely

```
    bool IsHeadings = true; //Does the data include a heading row?

    DataTable dt = GetDataTabletFromRemoteCsv(Url, IsHeadings)
```